# Is the Mongo DB object tried to a single Mongo instance?

Tags: java, mongodb, database

I spent some time search around for this and eventually had to go though the source to find out.

The question was; is the DB object from Mongo.getDb() tied to a single Mongo instance or will calls to it be made to all nodes in the cluster? Secondary, is the object thread safe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it is [thread safe](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Java+Driver+Concurrency), that one was easy. After going though the source, (version 2.9.1), I found that the entire list of ServerAddresses is passed in as part of the creation of the DB object.

Comment: +1 for not just finding your own answer but also sharing it with others instead of just cowardly deleting your question.